# How can I simulate a non-responding server?

Tags: javascript, apache

I have a web service which the customers use by inserting an external JavaScript (hosted on my servers). Recently, due to server outage - the external JavaScript became unavailable and my customers' websites came to a crawl as browser didn't load rest of the website until it loaded the JS (it goes into header of the websites).

I am trying to work out methods so that customers' website don't slow down even if my server goes down and for that I wanted to simulate a condition where the my server isn't responding. Note that if I specify a wrong URL, browser won't load the JS but in case URL is right and server isn't responding, browser will stall loading rest of the page. I want to simulate the last case. Any ideas how can I go about it?

PS: On server side, I am using the LAMP stack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a script that sleeps for a configurably long time

Something like

```
<?php
$how_long = $_GET['seconds'];
sleep($how_long);
echo "alert('Finished sleeping!');";
?>
```

Then you just access this script instead, for example by putting this in your HTML code 
`<script src="http://example.com/hang_for.php?seconds=3600" />`. That would sleep for an hour. There will be another timeouts that'll trigger first configured in php.ini, but that's exactly what you want to test, no?

Answer (score 2):

If the "P" in your LAMP is PHP, you could use the `sleep` function (documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)).  Then, have your test page load your PHP script as the source of your Javascript to see what happens.

Answer (score -3):

Unplug the server.  Having no power makes a server unresponsive...

Comment: He wants to *simulate* it.  Unplugging it *actually* makes it non-responsive.